# Famo.us Js - Animate Body (Particle) to Position

Tags: javascript, physics, famo.us

I have a `Circle` (which I'll refer to as `Particle` throughout the question) with a `Modifier` then a `Surface` added to it that pipes events to a  `Generic Sync` (Touch/Click). The `sync` events allow me to change the position of the `Particle` on `start`, `update` and `end` events so I can drag it around within a bounding box.

There's a rule in my application that **if the distance between the particle's position on the sync's `start` and `end` events is under a certain threshold, then the particle needs to animate back to the `start` position.**

For example: The particle starts at [0,0] on sync `start`, and is moved to [100,100]. The distance between the two points (about ~141.42) exceeds my threshold of 50...

**How can I apply a force/velocity/?? to animate the `Particle` back to [0,0]?**

*Note: I know I can do this with `Modifiers` pretty easily, but I'm trying to strictly use the Physics engine.*

**EDIT:** 
I figured out a solution that involves using a transitionable and setting an interval to run that constantly updates the particle's position, then setting the transitionable to my desired final position and clearing the interval in the transitionable's callback.

```
var retreatTrans = new Transitionable(myParticle.getPosition());

// Set a temporary interval to update the position
// as we change the transitionable (below)
var retreatInterval = setInterval(function () {
  myParticle.setPosition(retreatTrans.get());
});

// Set transitionable to our desired retreatPosition
retreatTrans.set([0,0], {duration: 100}, function () {
  // Clear our interval
  clearInterval(retreatInterval);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to drag a `particle/circle/rectangle` from an origin and then on touchend have the `particle/circle/rectangle` move back to the origin.

One of the ways to accomplish this withe the physics engine is through a `Spring`.  If you look at the `Scrollview`, internally it uses a spring to "bounce" back when you reach an edge.  I'll see if I can work up a quick implementation later to demonstrate this.

Comment: I've figured out a solution - might not be best practice, but I'll update my question with it now.

Comment: `Spring` is probably a better solution here - thanks for pointing it out. I'll try to work something out with it, but if you come up with something in the meantime please let me know. Thanks!